# Detect yellow spots on an image

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have a big raster image (12 GB) and I would like to detect yellow stains on it. I did try the Zonal Statistics but it is almost impossible to find the right parameters in order to detect the stain. Any better idea how do I do that?

Comment: what does the rest of the image look like? if it's all white then it's easy, if it's orangy yellow then it is hard.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of such a yellow stain?

Comment: @Erik image attached.

Comment: @IanTurtonI added an image.

Comment: @BERA yes, I am open to using other tools. Sorry, I can't share the coordinates.

Comment: Have you considered doing band  math, and making this into a single-band "yellow" image?

Comment: @Vince can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a hybrid classification approach. First using unsupervised classification method to point out the yellow stained class.  This yellow stained class may be combined from two or more classes. Then, try to calculate the statistics of this yellow-pixel class and identify yellow pixels with supervised classification method.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by unsupervised classification? what tool am I using for it?

Comment: Unsupervised classification is fully automatic run by software and need only to input parameters like maximum iteration, no of class. You can use Erdas or Envi to do it.